# Is $event necessary in Vuejs event handler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vue-component

I noticed people pass `$event` to listener functions, like this:

```
<li v-for="entry in entries">
  <div @dragenter="doStuff($event, entry)">
  ...


doStuff(event, entry){...
```

But is this really necessary? If I don't need to access $event object in the doStuff(), can I just pass my entry variable only? I noticed it works, but I want to know if it's something OK to do, or is $event there for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to pass `$event` if you want to deal with the original DOM event

From [the Vue.js docs](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html) (highlighting added by me):

> **Sometimes** we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You **can** pass it into a method using the special `$event` variable:

So, it's not a requirement, but an option. And it can indeed come in handy sometimes. But I normally omit it if I'm not making use of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends to the use case, sometimes you need to get the event object so you should pass it as a first parameter with that name `$event` like `handle($event [,...])`, if you don't need it you could simply pass your other parameters `handle([,...])` without that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

#### $event in vue event-handlers

...are there to access the eventData that is passed through to the event handler.

E.g.

In native DOM-Events you have several properties on the event object that might be of interest to you (target especially).

In vue-emitted Events you can pass data: `$emit('event-name', eventData)`. Your `$event` variable will take the value of this `eventData`.

**$event** is a special keyword vue uses. It allows you to pass the `eventData` as well as custom parameters to your event handlers.

Here is the official [doku](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `$event` if you don't need to know some detail, such as which key is pressed for keyboard event. Also, the order of parameter is not fixed, just match them on both html and js part is okay.